# MongoDB: Does returning the modified document after update affect performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

With the native MongoDB javascript driver, as well as with [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), the default behavior on updates is to not return the updated document in the callback/response.

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) explain that you need to set the `returnNewDocument: true` in order to get the updated document returned on updates.

(In the deprecated `findAndModify`, [as well as with Mongoose](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/), this [needs to be set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) with the `new: true` option):

My question is this: **Does returning the new, modified document have any impact on performance?**

For example, does this,

```
db.people.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: "Tom" },
    { $set: { score: 5 }},
    (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("done");
    }
);
```

run any faster than this?

```
db.people.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: "Tom" },
    { $set: { score: 5 }},
    { returnNewDocument: true },
    (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

Comment: probably, as the object has to be sent back over the wire.

Comment: @JonasWilms but the 'old' object also has to travel through the wire. The interesting bit is whether or not the operation takes longer to execute.

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, exactly. I am wondering if there is more operation / cycles that the DB has to go through to get the new copy of the database, rather than just saying it has been updated as soon as possible and returning the old document.

Comment: Create a database with 10.000 entries, then run both queries 10.000 times and find out wich runs faster. Thats the only way to know for sure, everything else is pure speculation

Comment: @AdamD Did you find out?